# SOA separate or group a functionality in endpoints?

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, soa

I am writing a WS and I am building the architecture but I have some questions.
For example, my front application need to fetch a list of users. Each user have a list of accounts, authorizations, capabilities. I am displaying a this list of users and when I click on a specific user, I would like to display his details (list of accounts, authorizations, capabilities).

So what is the best way to architect my WS?
In my opinion, I will make first an endpoint to get a list of user (simple just with id and name).
When I click on detail, I call another endpoint to get user detail.

But should I have to separate list of accounts, list of authorizations, list of capabilities in 3 endpoints (one per functionality). Each one become reusable. Or should I call a single endpoint that return all informations?

What are the best practices in SOA?

Answer (score 0):

So just using REST/SOAP services does not make your architecture SOA.SOA is an architectural style and set of disciplines and principles that can be implemented regardless of the underlying technology base.

How to design SOA services? Well the answer is really that this is decided in your SOA governance. WIthout governance SOA soon turns into a mess. So governance contrary to popular believe is not a set of restrictive rules on how to design your services, it defines a set of best practises and disciplines that you enforce to ensure maximum success of your solution.

SOA governance helps you make decisions during design and runtime. You mentioned you have SOA governance so what does your governance dictate.I would strongly suggest separate endpoint. Single responsibility principle is important.

A singular endpoint returning everything is going to be a pain to code, pain to maintain, pain to modify while being easy to call.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Actually we have a flexible SOA gouvernance and we use SOAP technology. So I am trying to find the best SOA architecture in this case.